# SQL Group records by a custom weekly time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

This is probably simple but I am constantly over-thinking my issues.

I need to pull all records within a certain date range (Jan - Mar 2018) that are between Sunday 12PM to Friday 1PM. Grouped by week

```
SELECT col1, 
       Sum(col2) 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT col1, 
                       col2, 
                       Datename(dw, [date_col]) AS day_of_week, 
                       date_col 
                FROM   table 
                WHERE  Datename(dw, [update_date]) != 'Saturday' 
               --eliminate Saturday records 
               ) a 
        WHERE  ( Cast(update_date AS TIME) < '12:00' 
                 AND day_of_week != 'Sunday' ) 
       --eliminate Sunday records before noon 
       ) b 
WHERE  ( day_of_week != 'Friday' 
          OR Cast(update_date AS TIME) > '13:00' ) 

--eliminate Friday records after 1PM
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: What does `select @@datefirst` give you? day of week related functions rely on this.

Comment: select @@datefirst returns 7

Comment: @Salman, language ok but how would date first setting effect the dayofweek name?

Comment: @CetinBasoz January 1 2018 is a Monday. `SET DATEFIRST 7 /* Sunday */; SELECT DATEPART(DW, '2018-01-01') /* 2 */` versus `SET DATEFIRST 1 /* Monday */; SELECT DATEPART(DW, '2018-01-01') /* 1 */`... different results depending on server settings.

Comment: @SalmanA, why would you use datepart(dw, ... ) for day of week NAME? Using your code slightly modified: SET DATEFIRST 7 /* Sunday */; 
SELECT DATENAME(DW, '2018-01-01') /* Monday */
versus 
SET DATEFIRST 1 /* Monday */; 
SELECT DATENAME(DW, '2018-01-01') /* Monday */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following condition:

```
WHERE update_date >= '2018-01-01' -- between Jan 2018
AND   update_date <  '2018-04-01' -- and Mar 2018
AND (
    DATENAME(dw, update_date) = 'Sunday' AND CAST(update_date AS TIME) >= '12:00' OR
    DATENAME(dw, update_date) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday') OR
    DATENAME(dw, update_date) = 'Friday' AND CAST(update_date AS TIME) < '13:00'
)
```

Comment: I stand corrected, it was my mistake. Removing my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to reflect correct return values for DATEPART(dw, ...)

You can perform the logic to determine which day/hour combos are valid inside a CASE statement in a sub-query SELECT and then group by week number in an outer query. This would simplify the WHERE clause.  I find this style a little less opaque and easier to maintain long-term.

The example below was tested on Microsoft SQL SERVER.

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(wk, Update_Date) AS GroupByWeek
    , col1
    , SUM(col2)
FROM (
    SELECT
        col1
        , col2
        , Update_Date
        , CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, Update_Date) = 1 AND DATEPART(hh, Update_Date) >= 12 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, Update_Date) = 6 AND DATEPART(hh, Update_Date) < 13 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, Update_Date) BETWEEN 2 AND 5 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS FallsInWindow
    FROM table
) RowsInWindow
WHERE 
    RowsInWindow.Update_Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-01'
    AND RowsInWindow.FallsInWindow = 1
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(wk, Update_Date)
    , col1
ORDER BY GroupByWeek
```

Comment: Why do you need the subquery?

Comment: `DATEPART` can return different values depending on `@@DATEFIRST` variable.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - You don't need a sub-query. I find this style easier to read and maintain, though. The WHERE clause is simplified using a sub-query.  The sub-query could also easily be put into a VIEW which allows the logic determining FallsInWindow to be abstracted away and shared by other modules.

Comment: @SalmanA - Thanks for the information about @@DATEFIRST. I wasn't aware of that detail.

Comment: Also DATEPART is supposed to return number between 1 and 7, not 0 and 6.

Comment: @StevenKrise, if you don't change the language, date settings wouldn't change the day of week names in any way (Monday is always Monday for example). That is why you should use DateName, instead of DatePart as in OP's query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, Sum(col2)
                FROM   [table] 
                WHERE  Datename(dw, [update_date]) <> 'Saturday'
                OR
                NOT ( Cast(update_date AS TIME) < '12:00' 
                      AND Datename(dw, [update_date]) == 'Sunday' )
                OR 
                NOT ( Datename(dw, [update_date]) == 'Friday' 
                      AND Cast(update_date AS TIME) > '13:00' )
group by col1, datepart(week, update_date);
```

Comment: This won't group the data by week.

Comment: How do you know col1 is nor week? Anyway I can add one another grouping.